# Rust: How to connect inner nodes T of Rc<RefCell<T>> of a tree structure

Tags: rust, serde, refcell

Consider the following code:

```
use serde_json::{Value, json};

let data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(json!({})));
let sub = Rc::new(RefCell::new(json!({})));

{
    let mut v = sub.borrow_mut();
    v["a"] = json!(true);
};
{
    let mut data_borrowed = data.borrow_mut();
    let new_data_value = sub.take();
    data_borrowed["sub"] = new_data_value;
}
{
    let mut v = sub.borrow_mut();
    v["b"] = json!(true);
};

println!("{:#?}", data);
```

This outputs

```
RefCell {
    value: Object {
        "sub": Object {
            "a": Bool(true),
        },
    },
}
```

I want to have `data.sub` containing both `a` and `b` even though `b` is pushed into `sub` after `sub` is defined as a child of `data`. However I couldn't find a way to do so without using `take`, and `take` here doesn't work because of in-memory substitution

How could I achieve that ? `sub.borrow_mut().deref_mut()` returns a `&mut Value` which I cannot seem to use - an owned Value is needed. But the owner of Value is the above RefCell.

My requirement is to have dynamic (recursive) building of a serde::json::Value with potential closures which insert additional data afterwards, and at the very end be able to read the whole structure (hence the Rc<RefCell>). But I can't find a way to connect intermediate nodes which are contained within their own RefCell.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with the data types from `serde_json`, because you can't store an `Rc` in them, but it's possible if you define your own structs.

Comment: @PitaJ Actually it is possible with "rc" flag enabled for serde package. Not sure about RefCell though, nor if it is possible to connect them as I need them to be. I will think about making custom Tree struct, thank you for the idea.